# How to disable Google Chrome downloads from Ubuntu updates?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, updates, uninstall

How can I stop the Ubuntu Update from trying to download Google Chrome when it notifies me of updates?

I uncheck it every time, but it keeps coming back.

Comment: Breathe man, just breathe...

Answer (score 2):

Try to uninstall Chrome from your package manager. Does it work, or are there some errors?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I suggest you to install Chromium instead of Chrome. They only have slight difference but Chromium is in Ubuntu packages and fits Ubuntu better.

Then, to disable update of Chromium, firstly you need to pick the version you like.

1. Go to Synaptic Package Manager, search Chromium and select it.
2. Hit "Package" in top menu and choose "Force version"
3. In the dropdown, select the version you like.
4. If there is no version you like, you need to uninstall it and download a version manually to install.

After that, you can "Lock" the version now. Still in Synaptic Package Manager, hit "Package"->"Lock version". Done.

Now your favourite version is locked. Ubuntu will no longer notify you any updates until you unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Deinstall chrome with your package manager and than install it 'by hand' without the package-manager. This way the update service does not know that chrome is installed and therefore will not suggest to update it.

By the way, why do you not want to update chrome?